# Assimp not loading hierarchy of obj file exported from blender

Tags: graphics, blender, assimp

I made a model in blender with hierarchy looking like this

[image]

exported it as .obj file

then I loaded this file in opengl with Assimp

```
Assimp::Importer importer;

const auto * scene = importer.ReadFile(filename, aiProcess_Triangulate);

if (!scene || scene->mFlags & AI_SCENE_FLAGS_INCOMPLETE || !scene->mRootNode)
{
    Logger->log(importer.GetErrorString());
    return;
}
```

the mRootNode contains 30 children, which is the number of objects in the scene but each of these child contains no children so it seems like either Assimp discarded the hierarchy information or blender didn't output the hierarchy information.

can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Obj file is a text, you can open it in any text editor to see what's there. It doesn't support neither parent-child hierarchy nor bones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a knows bug in the obj-importer from Assimp. We do not store the group hierarchy correctly. It would be great to get a small example that I can try to fix the issue, because in the past I didn't find the time for it.

Thanks a lot for fingerpointing me :-)!

Kim

Comment: first of all, thank you so much for your time and effort put into this project. I think as @keltar mentioned obj files do not support parent-child hierarchy, I made an example https://github.com/defuyun/obj-example this repo, the scene contains 1 parent cube and 2 children cubes but the obj file does not contain any parent child information. loaded the file in blender and the file hierarchy was also not preserved. so in conclusion it's probably not a bug